# could not find function "FUNcluster" in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to run kmeans clustering on my data and show the plot using this code:
Elbow method is used to calculate number of *k*.

```
library(tidyverse)  # data manipulation
library(cluster)    # clustering algorithms
library(factoextra) # clustering algorithms & visual
library(NbClust)    #use zip file to install it 

wss <- function(k) {
  kmeans(df_km, k, nstart = 25 )$tot.withinss
}

# Compute and plot wss for k = 1 to k = 32
k.values <- 1:32
wss_values <- map_dbl(k.values, wss)

set.seed(123)
fviz_nbclust(df_km, FUNcluster =  kmeans, method = "wss")
```

in the last line of code, it shows this error:

```
Error in FUNcluster(x, i, ...) : could not find function "FUNcluster"
```

I tried to restart session, also used .zip, CRAN, and also this link to download the "factoextra"
 devtools::install_github("kassambara/factoextra")

But still I get the error. Any solution to solve it?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue with `fviz_nbclust(iris.scaled, kmeans, method = "silhouette")` from the example help page

Comment: @akrun After couple of hours struggling, I had to close RStudio and open it again. The error was gone.

Comment: Probably, some env issue